# verify phone number everytime i login like whays app using firebase opt

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I want to verify phone number every time I login into the app using firebase opt but it only verifies if the user is not created. After that it sign in without verification. 
Is there a way to verify phone number every time I login (for security purposes).

I am using the following code

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phone,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            Main2Activity.this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                       PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                    mVerificationId = verificationId;
                    mResendToken = token;
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sign the user out with:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

And start the flow again by calling `verifyPhoneNumber`.